# What is the 'type surrounded by string' syntax in Python and how does it work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I'm struggling to find the name of this syntax. I ran into it when I was having trouble with a recursive custom type which was triggering a Pylance error (using Python 3.9.13):

```py
@dc
class FooBar:
    foo: int
    bar: int
    
    def MakeFooBar(self) -> FooBar:  # "FooBar" is not defined Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable)
        return FooBar(1,2)
```

I fussed around and found a fix to this by surrounding the return type with a string. This resolved the issue and preserve the type for the static analyzer beautifully:

```py
@dc
class FooBar:
    foo: int
    bar: int
    
    def MakeFooBar(self) -> 'FooBar':  # This is fine 
        return FooBar(1,2)
```

What is this syntax called? How does it work?

I've tried searching "type", "typing" and "surrounded by string" but I can only find 1 million beginner articles on string types not on this syntax

Comment: This is called “an ugly hack”.

Comment: Turns out it's called a "forward reference" and it's classy  see pep-484 https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references